# Deleting rows where all elements are missing value from list-R

Tags: r

Let I have a list(list1) which consists data frames(df1, df2, ..dfn) where each data frame has different number of columns.

Let `list1[[1]]`:

```
df1:

indx  v1  v2  
1     23  45
2     NA  34
3     NA  NA
4     NA  NA
5     56  NA
```

and

```
df2:

indx  v9  v6  
1     5   15
2     11  78
3     16  NA
4     NA  NA
5     NA  8
```

I want to delete rows where all elemetns of rows(except the indx row) are NA.

So the ouput should be(list2)

`list2[[1]]`:

```
df1:

indx  v1  v2  
1     23  45
2     NA  34
5     56  NA
```

and

```
df2:

indx  v9  v6  
1     5   15
2     11  78
3     16  NA
5     NA  8
```

How can I do this using R? I will be very glad fotr any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `lapply`, get the `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`!is.na(x[-1])`), convert to logical vector by checking the elements are not equal to 0 and use that to subset the rows.

```
lapply(list1, function(x) x[!!rowSums(!is.na(x[-1])),])
#$df1
#  indx v1 v2
#1    1 23 45
#2    2 NA 34
#5    5 56 NA

#$df2
#  indx v9 v6
#1    1  5 15
#2    2 11 78
#3    3 16 NA
#5    5 NA  8
```